# Google translate in python

Tags: python, google-translate

When using this code from https://stackabuse.com/text-translation-with-google-translate-api-in-python/

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

result = translator.translate("Mitä sinä teet")

print(result.src)
print(result.dest)
print(result.origin)
print(result.text)
```

I get 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'', and i was wondering what is wrong, the error seems to be on the 'result = tra...' line,

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was too getting this same error. I think there is a issue in the current release. But the new alpha version worked fine.

First uninstall current version :

```
pip uninstall googletrans
```

Then install this one :

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the installation of the library because the code worked fine for me. I would suggest you to uninstall and then reinstall the googletrans library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, filename), encoding='utf-8') as html:
            soup = BeautifulSoup('<pre>' + html.read() + '</pre>', 'html.parser')
            for title in soup.findAll('title'):
                recursively_translate(title)
```

See this 2 complete code that can easy translate files with python:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

**OR**

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/example-python-google-translate-any-text-html-file-version-2.html